# OpenCV threshold color image (by brightness, not per channel)

Tags: c++, opencv

openCV seems to be doing per-channel threshold if I use `cv::threshold` on color image.

I use it to get rid of pixels that are not bright enough (`cv::THRESH_TOZERO`), and then overlay that (`cv::add`) on other image.

Works almost OK, but the problem is that it obviously works per-channel, so the colors get sometimes distorted (i.e. some of the channels get zeroed and others not). What I need is "zero out pixels whose brightness is not large enough".

Now I know I could iterate over the image in for cycle and just overwrite the pixel with zero if the sum of the channels is not over the threshold. But that's almost certainly not going to be performant enough to be run real-time on the low-power device I target (nVidia Jetson Xavier NX). OpenCV functions seem to be much better optimized.

Thanks!

Comment: The common solution is converting from BGR to Grayscale and applying the threshold on the gray image.

Comment: OK, but I need to keep the colors. Maybe if I used the the gray image as a mask somehow...

Comment: The result of `cv::threshold` is a binary image - use it as a mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the solution is to convert to grayscale, do the threshold which gives you a mask, and then do `bitwise_and` to only keep the pixels you want. Like this:

```
                cv::UMat mask;
                cv::cvtColor(img, mask, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
                cv::threshold(mask, mask, threshold, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
                cv::cvtColor(mask, mask, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

                cv::bitwise_and(img, mask, img);
```